# How have a zebra style CSS for HTML table?

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to make a Zebra style on my PHP table for each row. Now with the above CSS code that i have:

```
table.imagetable td:nth-child(odd) 
{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

I have Zebra style but only for each column which is not desirable. Any ideas of how to figure it out?

Comment: Why not tr instead of td?

Comment: i've tried. But it wasn't working

Comment: You could also do two css classes and alternate them on each row.

Comment: Also out of curiousity, which browser are you using?

Comment: Currently, i use Chrome

Comment: @ather0s can you edit your post with your html table? and if posible a image show what do you want ;-)

Comment: @ather0s do you solved your problem?

Comment: you had a typo maybe? It just works to change td to tr: https://jsfiddle.net/g7rzrp46/

Comment: and then you could add table.imagetable tr {display:block} for style...

Comment: oh my, i see this question is mighty old already :)

Answer (score 3):

As shown below, you can use the nth-of-type selector:

```
/* Changes the background color of every odd row to light gray */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Changes the weight of each td cell within each odd row to bold */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Collapses table borders to make the table appear continuous */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Spaces out each table cell */
table td {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```css
/* Changes the background color of every odd row to light gray */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Changes the weight of each td cell within each odd row to bold */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Collapses table borders to make the table appear continuous */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Spaces out each table cell */
table td {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need put something like this for your even rows

```
table.imagetable tr:nth-child(even) 
{
  background-color:#fff;
}
```

Comment: yes but this is working only for each column, not for each row

Comment: @ather0s you got some advance with the edit of my answer? If you solve your problem don't forget check as correct

Comment: can you edit your post with your html table? and if posible a image show what do you want

Answer (score 0):

You have to write on your table row:

```
<tr class="<?=($c++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even' ?>" style="border:1">
```

Then on your css you add:

```
<style type="text/css">
.even { background-color:#FFFFFF } 
.odd { background-color:#EAEAEA }
</style>
```

Good luck!