# PHP Table Apply CSS

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have PHP table as follows:

```
echo "<table border='2'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo"<th>Username</th>";
echo"<th>Forename</th>";
echo"<th>Surname</th>";
echo"<th>Course</th>";
echo"<th>Subject</th>";
echo"<th>Level</th>";
echo"<th>Date</th>"; 
echo"<th>Time</th>";
echo"</tr>";

$count = 0;
while ($count < $numrow)  
{
$row = $re->fetch_assoc();
extract($row);    
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td>";
echo $username;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $firstName;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $surname;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $course;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $subject;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $level;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $date;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>";
echo $time;
echo "</td>";

echo "</tr>";

$count = $count + 1;
```

What is the best way to apply CSS to the table? Such as different colours, etc not just positioning. I have tried giving the table an ID or name or class and nothing works. I can give the parent DIV CSS but it gives the DIV as a whole the CSS, rather than individual rows/columns etc. So for example what is the best way to apply CSS to those PHP columns/rows?

Comment: "Nothing works" isn't very helpful. Since your problem is a client-side one, there's no use in including your PHP source. Please update your question to include a sample of the HTML generated by your page, including the CSS you're trying to apply. If you create a rule for `tr` or `td`, it _will_ apply to the appropriate elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can depend on your knowledge of CSS and using stylesheets by assign ID's and classes or whether you did inline styles.

It's easier to assign styles specifically to elements such as styling the `table tbody tr` in CSS then adding a class with overriding styles, or inline overriding styles.

Your question isn't actually that helpful but i'm hoping this fiddle will help you grasp what you need to do:

https://jsfiddle.net/4y21mvhe/

Answer (score 1):

As shown below, you can use the nth-of-type selector:

```
/* Changes the background color of every odd row to light gray */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Changes the weight of each td cell within each odd row to bold */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Collapses table borders to make the table appear continuous */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Spaces out each table cell */
table td {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```css
/* Changes the background color of every odd row to light gray */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Changes the weight of each td cell within each odd row to bold */
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Collapses table borders to make the table appear continuous */
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Spaces out each table cell */
table td {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td>Cell 2</td>
    <td>Cell 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Read mote at:

> [How have a zebra style CSS for HTML table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28573300/3653989)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```css
<td style="background-color:red".....> OR
<th style="background-color:red"..... >
```